# Why is my muslin (cheesecloth) sticking to my seitan?

Tags: seitan

Why is my muslin (cheesecloth) sticking to my seitan? I've cooked it in broth for two hours (flipping once), and now I'm trying to remove the cheesecloth, but it's all stuck to the outer layer. Did I leave it too long? Is there anything that can be done to salvage the outer layer?

Answer (score 1):

The cheese cloth is porous enough for the seitan to expand through during the cook process. Try a looser wrap with the cheesecloth. If you steam it in the cheesecloth it will absorb less liquid and not expand as much.
When this has happened, I have had limited success removing the cloth and preserving all of the outer layer. If the seitan is not too embedded, let it cool on a rack 5 minutes and then try to slowly peel off the cloth. More than 5 and it is a hardened mess.